# I can't delete image file because its used by anther process

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I can't delete the image file because, it's used by anther process after I create it. The problem happens when my process is running. How can I terminate the process that has the file open, so other processes will be able to access it?

I used this code to create the image file:

```
string uploads = Path.Combine(Hosting.WebRootPath, "uploads");
string fullPath = Path.Combine(uploads, fileName);
entity.file.CopyTo(new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create));FileMode.Create));
```

[image description 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTw5s.jpg)

File explorer can't read the image file, `java-logo-png-300x300`, until I stop running the project in VS.

[image description 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n973q.jpg)

Comment: Is the image being displayed in the web page anywhere? How the image was placed at that ligation /

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya when I add new book which is have image, I cannot do delete for book in same run because the image is under "add process"... If I do stop and new run for project I can delete it normally.

Comment: @DourHighArch  I don't have wrong in my code, I thing I have to write code to cut process with the file after add it.   ///// entity.file.CopyTo(new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am a bit confused on what the issue is but, from the looks of things, you never close the `FileStream`. When you open a file stream in that manner, the file's `ShareMode` is set to None so no other process can read/write/delete the file. All you need to really do is change the last line from:

```
entity.file.CopyTo(new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create));
```

to

```
//Opens the file
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
{
    //Copies data from entity.file to stream
    entity.file.CopyTo(stream);
}
//File was released (disposed of) thanks to the using statement
```

After the copy is done, the file is released so other processes will be able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. But you can wait till the process finish, you can use `FileInfo.IsFileLocked()` to verify if your file is in use.

Sample code:

```
public static void Test(){
    FileInfo inf = new FileInfo("your_file");

    while (inf.IsFileLocked()) {
      Console.WriteLine("File locked, wait...");
    };
}
```

Important: *Remember to close streams every time you open them, as this may cause file locks.*

Answer (score 0):

As other shown, one reason might be that you are not wrapping your stream statement in a using block, or manually disposing them.